# Do I need another sump pump for an addition with a basement?

Tags: basement, sump-pump, addition

We are doing an addition in a 50yr old house in New England,  in an existing house with basement and sump pump. The new addition includes a new basement adjacent to the existing one towards the lower gradient side. Snow is an issue in NE and we do see the existing pump kick-in during snow melting season and heavy rain. We are wondering if we need another pump in the new basement, as this will be a finished space. Concrete guy says we don't, but I want to get an opinion from the community here. Both basement will be in the same level. If water accumulates (water table rise) in snow-melt season will the older sumppump be enough?

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer. Please provide a sketch or better description of the home's footprint, as well as details about the new and existing drain fields, such as substrate and tile layout.

Answer (score 2):

What will happen if the original pump stops.

Do you have flood insurance ?

Check with them if you need second dedicated pump.

I would install second pump and sleep better.

Answer (score 2):

Under all normal conditions, assuming you have an adequate layer of crushed stone under the slab, you probably don't need another pump. However --

The existing pump will fail one day. Maybe not until you are long gone, but maybe it will fail on your watch. How will you learn that it failed? Is there a water alarm to alert you to rising water? Do you keep a spare sump pump ready to install? Or will the first sign of trouble be the squishy sound when you reach the bottom of the basement stairs?

You have a perfect opportunity to build-in backup by making a new sump in the new concrete and installing a new sump pump in it. You can leave them both powered all the time. Maybe they will both operate during snow melt season. But they will not both fail at the same time as long as you have electric power. That should give you added peace of mind that your investment in a finished basement will be protected.

Remember, your homeowner's policy does not cover damage from **rising water**. You need a separate flood insurance policy for that. Lacking that, dual sump pumps would be excellent insurance.

Comment: generally a good idea though with a dual location you have the additional complication of adding piping and electrical and having a second service area.  Ideally you install a backup with your primary.  I have 2 in my pit.  one for standard operation, one set at a high level to kick in if primary fails or water ingress exceeds output.  the primary  is ac but hooked to a pumpspy 1500W that hooks to a marine battery in power outage conditions.  I use the HC6000 electronic floats.

Answer (score 1):

If your existing basement has a good layer of 3/4 crush below the slab and the new addition is at the same level as the existing then any ground water that comes in will flow through the drain rock as intended and enter the existing sump.

Since you are at the pre-slab portion of your project if you haven't already you should put in some 4" pipe that could be used in the future to depressurize your slab in case you find you have high radon levels.